# C++, class with method and enum type - can method and enum value have same names?

Tags: c++, class, enums, redefinition

I have the following class:

```
class washm_t 
{
public:
    enum door_t { closed = 0, open = 1 };
private:
    door_t door_state ;
public:
    int open() ;
};
```

The problem with the class is that the `open` name is defined as both the name of the method inside of the class and the value of the enum type.

The question is: can I somehow modify the code so that both `open` names work inside of the class or should I pick some other name for the `open()` method or for the `open` enum type value?

This is how the `open()` function looks like:

```
int washm_t::open()
{
    if(door_state == open)          // ~fails, 'open' interpreted as name of method
                                            //  not as name of enum type value
        return 1 ;
    else
        return door_state = open, 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11 you can use `enum class`:

```
enum class door_t { closed = 0, open = 1 };
```

But then you have to refer to `door_t::open` instead of simply `open`. This has the advantages and disadvantages of verboseness. `enum class` is good in these cases where a name conflict is likely, and it effectively adds a generic prefix to the enumerators of the enumeration.

(Actually, in C++11 you don't need to use the `class` keyword. Simply referring to `door_t::open` resolves the conflict with no other change.)

You can arrive at a similar solution in C++03 by putting an `enum` inside a `class` (hence the syntax of the C++11 feature)

```
struct door_state {
    enum door_t { closed = 0, open = 1 };
};
```

You can make this a nested class, or define it before `washm_t` and use it as a base class

```
class washm_t : public door_state {
    int open();
};
```

Now the the member `open()` overrides the enumerator, but the enumerator is still available as `door_state::open`, and `closed` is still available using the same syntax as before.

Answer (score 2):

How about capitalizing the enums, or giving them a sensible prefix?

```
enum door_t { CLOSED = 0, OPEN = 1 };

enum door_t { door_closed = 0, door_open = 1 };
```

Comment: What about giving the function a more expressive name, like `openDoor`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have symbols under the same namespace or scope with the same name. Compiler can't differentiate one from the other.

The problem here is with the coding convention. I usually prefer to use caps letters for named constants like enums

```
enum door_t { CLOSED = 0, OPEN = 1 };
```

Comment: And even if the compiler can differentiate them, it's a pretty poor idea for HUMANS to have to figure out which one is meant.

Comment: All caps is normally used only for macros, to call attention to the fact that the name _doesn't_ obey scoping, and might do almost anything.

Comment: yes all caps for macros and I've seen enums using all caps (but unlike macros, it will usually have a prefix), but that just naming convention. Yes, name and scope are two different aspects of any programming language. Did I mean otherwise?